# Why does this C++ program print "2"?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm new to **C++**, but here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I input letters, it always prints `x = 2`. I know that I'm supposed to input digits, but why "2"?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you have undefined behavior.  You should *never* use any input values without first checking that the input succeeded.  Accessing an input value when the input fails (and it will if you enter alpha for an int) will leave the value in its previous state—if you've never initialized it otherwise, uninitialized (and accessing an uninitialized value is undefined behavior).

Answer (score 5):

Because `x` is indeterminate - you haven't given it a value. Change it to `int x = 42;`, and it will give you a determined value.

If `operator >>` (which is what happens in `cin >> x`) doesn't change the value of `x` when it doesn't find at least one digit (after skipping any whitespace) in the input.

You can (and should) check that `cin` is successful with `if (cin >> x) ... safe to use x ...; else cout << errormessage;`.

But I was trying to explain "how come it is 2", not "here's chapter and verse on reading input."

Comment: Because accessing `x` is undefined behavior.  An implementation _could_ (and a good debugging implementation would) cause the program to crash.

Comment: @JamesKanze /cc Mats what about the `cin >> x;`?

Comment: Better yet, using `if (std::cin >> x) cout << "x = " << x << '\n';` to avoid printing it if it wasn't set properly. And @NarakkaSan - don't use `system("pause")`... `std::cin.get()` is better (flushes and is portable).

Comment: I'm confused. I'm 100% sure I wrote that "using an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour" and got a downvote because it was wrong, the value of a variable is indeterminate. A pointer that is uninitialized will be UB.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore He said "Whenever I input letters".  Inputing letters when reading an `int` will cause the input to fail, leaving the variable in its previous state (which in this case, was uninitialized).

Comment: Depends how you use it - you can still set it. It's entirely valid if the input succeeds.

Comment: @JamesKanze I know, was just trying to pry a better explanation.

Comment: @MatsPetersson An integral or floating point value as well (with the exception of `char` or `unsigned char`).  Everything but `char` and `unsigned char` can have trapping values.

Comment: I think in this case it's not *undefined*, but rather *implementation* defined. It is up to the implementation what value `x` will have. But I don't think a standard conforming compiler is allowed to cause *this* program to crash.

Comment: "I'm 100% sure I wrote that..." - whoever told you that you were wrong gave you a major bum steer.

Comment: @Axel ummm, no, it's UB to read from an un-initialized variable.

Comment: So, taking this "UB" idea a little further: Assuming we have an architecture with parity bits on memory, and the stack is "virgin memory" (that is, it hasn't been written to with ANYTHING), would the system be non-compliant when you read an uninitialized value from an array of `char` and drop you in the parity error trap handler then?

Comment: @Axel The standard explicitly says that the behavior is
undefined in this case, and I can easily imagine implementations
where it might crash.  See §4.1/1 in C++11: "[...] or if the
object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this
[lvalue-to-rvalue] conversion has undefined behavior."  This
applies to _every_ type in the system (but there are explicit
exceptions for `char` and `unsigned char` elsewhere).

Comment: @MatsPetersson The classical example of a trapping `int` is a system using 1's complement, in which all expressions create positive 0's, and which traps on a negative 0.  There's text elsewhere which guarantees access as a `char` or `unsigned char` works _after_ the memory for the object has been allocated, but before it has been initialized, so you can't have parity failure.  (But if negative 0 traps, plain `char` must be unsigned---which is the case on all non-2's complement machines I know of.)